# PHP - What is wrong with my code?

Tags: php, validation, formula

I have this original formula from a medical research book:

> Log(e) (EFW) = (-4.564+(0.282*AC)-(0.00331*AC^2))*1000

EFW (grams), AC (cm)

this is what i did:

```
$ac = 291; // (mm)
$w = log(-4.564+(0.282*($ac/10))-(0.00331*pow(($ac/10),2)))*1000);
echo "result: " . $w;


result: 6.7
```

the result should be between 1900-2500 grams, but not 6.7 grams.
I do not have any clue what is wrong here? would you please take a look for me, Thank you!

Edit: I would like to have the result in gramm, and my AC is in mm

Comment: Your code has a missing paren somewhere: http://codepad.org/GDSWjEDU

Comment: Why are you dividing $ac/10 when it's not in the original formula?

Comment: What is `AC` and the **actual result** from your book?

Comment: @creminsn: The formula is in centimeters and he's feeding it a millimeter value.  Which, for starters, is unintuitive...

Comment: @david, sorry just realised that now. apologies.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the `log()` is on the left side in the original and on the right side in the implementation.  What "result" does the original actually produce?

Comment: http://codepad.org/yVmzaToZ Yes, change `log()` to `exp()`, and have fun.

Comment: @Leigh: AC stays for Abdominal circumference (ultrasound)

Comment: @biziclop: oh yes, your solution is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- if Log( result ) == expr
- then result == exp( expr )

http://codepad.org/yVmzaToZ

Code:

```
$ac = 291; // (mm)
$w = exp(
  -4.564
  +(0.282*($ac/10))
  -(0.00331*pow(($ac/10),2))
)*1000;
echo "result: " . $w;
```

Result:

```
result: 2314.6509531657
```

Which is between 1900-2500 :)

Comment: Although the answer looks correct according to the OP comment on the expected range, shouldn't the `*1000` be inside the `exp()`? (yes I'm aware this ruins everything ;)) - could also be that the formula from the book isn't right, or is mis-quoted here.

Comment: Yes, it couldn't ruin more: result will be INF :)

Comment: I tracked down the formula. It's for body weight in twins. `Campbell:
Log e(BW)=-4.564+0.282(AC)-0.00331(AC)^2` - The *1000 was incorrect. Your answer is correct :)